# How to Parse RSS Data with JSON

Tags: json, rss

As a noob, I'm trying to parse a weather.com RSS feed for display on my site.  The code below successfully retrieves the data and displays it as an alert.  My question is how to take this further and parse the resulting feed instead of just displaying it?  The goal is to take parts of the response and embed it into the HTML on the page.  For example, if I wanted to output a table that has a row with the current temperature, what would be the syntax?

```
<script>
function parseRSS(url, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&num=10&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      callback(data.responseData.feed);
    }
  });
}


parseRSS('http://rss.weather.com/weather/rss/local/USAK0012?cm_ven=LWO&cm_cat=rss&par=LWO_rss', 
function(json)
{
  alert("Result: " + JSON.stringify(json));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it helps anyone, here is how I ended up doing it.  I went with the feed from accuweather.com, instead of weather.com, just because I happened to get it working first.

1) Obtained the value of the feed "title" field, which contained the current weather values that I needed.

```
var weatherFeed = json;
var currentConditions = weatherFeed.entries[0].title;
```

2) Extracted the specific elements, for example currentTemperature:

```
var firstColonIndex = currentConditions.indexOf(":");
var secondColonIndex = currentConditions.indexOf(":", firstColonIndex + 1);
var currentTemperature = currentConditions.substring(secondColonIndex + 1);
```

3) Built the HTML using jQuery and embedded the extracted weather values, then put the whole thing within a Div element on my page:

```
<div class="tile-content" id="MyCityWeather">
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var weatherElement = "#MyCityWeather";
    var temperatureElement = $("<h2/>",
    {
      style: "margin-left: 25px!important; font-size: 46px!important;"
    });
    temperatureElement.append(currentTemperature);
    temperatureElement.appendTo(weatherElement);
  </script>
</div>
```